# Excel VBA Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients -- inconsistent error

Tags: excel, vba

There are a number of issues with this error, but none seem to match my case exactly so posting in the hope of some help.

I have a macro which takes all the files in a directory, opens them silently in a new (hidden) instance of Excel and does two "Save As" operations: one to a location on SharePoint and one to an archive folder. The purpose of this is that the files are produced by SAS in XML format with an XLS extension. Saving them as native XLSX reduces file size dramatically.

Each day we produce a number of files which we then run the macro on. It has been erroring on the same file each day; that is to say it's not *exactly* the same file, but the same report with different versions each day. It is the largest of the files, but other than that there's nothing outstanding about it.

There are two other oddities:

1. When running the code step-by-step with F8, the error doesn't occur - this has meant I've been unable to pinpoint exactly where it's erroring;
2. The code has an option to skip files that error - when skipping and rerunning it again immediately afterwards, with no other changes, the error doesn't occur the second time.

Here's the code; the macro is called different times with different locations as parameters:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory(inPath As String, sharepointPath As String, archivePath As String)
    Dim sDir As String
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim mbErr As Integer, mbFinished As Integer

    If Right(inPath, 1) <> "\" Then inPath = inPath & "\"

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

    sDir = Dir$(inPath, vbNormal)

    Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
        On Error GoTo LoopError:
        app.Visible = False
        app.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add(inPath & sDir)
        With wb
            .SaveAs Filename:=sharepointPath & Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".")) & "xlsx", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, ReadOnlyRecommended:=True
            .SaveAs Filename:=archivePath & Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".")) & "xlsx", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        Set wb = Nothing
        app.DisplayAlerts = True
        app.Quit
        Kill (inPath & sDir) ' delete the file

NextFile:
        sDir = Dir$ ' find the next filename
    Loop

    mbFinished = MsgBox( _
        "The process has finished. You may need to review any files that have errored.", _
        vbOKOnly, _
        "Process finished" _
        )

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    mbErr = MsgBox( _
        "There has been an error finding files. Check the SharePoint folder and try again.", _
        vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
        "Error finding files" _
        )
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

LoopError:
    Select Case MsgBox("There has been an error with " & sDir & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        "The error is " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        Err.Description & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        "Press OK to continue with the next file or Cancel to stop the process.", _
                        vbCritical + vbOKCancel, "Error")
        Case vbOK
            Resume NextFile ' go back and try the next file
        Case vbCancel
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Sub ' stop processing the files
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert a waiting loop, perhaps with DoEvents or just a straight-forward 1 second Wait, to allow the hardware to catch up? Deletion often takes longer than saving.

Comment: @Variatus Can you let me know how I would do that please? And at what point in the code? Thanks.

Comment: My experience is that there are indeed timing issues in saving/closing a file and deleting it. Another issue is that you are calling `Kill` from a `Dir` enumeration, modifying the collection that `Dir` needs to enumerate, which means the result [may not be consistent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160210-00/?p=93011).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to insert the sub below underneath your existing code, outside your procedure but in the same code module.

```
Private Sub WaitASecond(ByVal Sec As Single)

    Dim WaitTill As Single

    WaitTill = Timer + Sec
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop While Timer < WaitTill
End Sub
```

Call it from your main procedure with a line of code like this.

```
WaitASecond(0.5)     ' which would wait for half a second
```

Experiment with both the length of time, in increments of 0.25 seconds, if you like, and the location of the code. Bear in mind that it seems that your biggest file creates the problem. So, you might limit the call to that one file or vary the length of the wait depending upon the file size (if it makes a significant difference to your process).
You might instroduce a wait after each SaveAs, only after both SaveAs and/or after the Kill.